# problems with numpy dimensions using the [:] syntax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, syntax, indexing

I've got a question...

I created a `numpy.array` with the `shape=(4,128,256,256)`.
If I print out the following:

```
print shape(x[:][3][1][:])
```

the output is `shape=(256,256)`, not `(4,256)` as I expected...
Also the statement

```
print x[:][4][1][1]
```

produces an error: `index out of bounds`

After some try and error it seems to me that the [:] do not work if another argument with discrete value follows...

I solved my current problem by using loops, but for the future I want to understand what I did wrong...

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want you must do indecing properly:

```
x[:, 3, 1, :].shape => (4, 256)
```

`numpy` arrays are not standard lists

If you do `x[:][3][1][:]` you actually do the following:

```
x1 = x[:]  # get the whole array
x2 = x1[3] # get the fourth element along the first dimension
x2.shape => (128, 256, 256)
x3 = x2[1] # get the second element along the first dimension of `x2`
x3.shape => (256, 256)
x3[:]   # get all `x3`
```

For more explanations about indexing see [the numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

---

About the error when you do

```
x[:][4][1][1]
```

You get a `index out of bounds` because `x[:]` is the whole array and the first dimension is 4, so `x[:][4]` does not exists